# Combining ng-grid and ui-select2: unable to select a value

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid, ui-select2

In the editableCellTemplate of an ng-grid, I wanted to use a more user-friendly dropdown, and I found ui-select2 to be a good one.

The thing is however, that any click on this component, when it is used inside the ng-grid, results in the cell juming back to non-editable mode.

This way I can't select another value using the mouse (I can using the arrows on my keyboard).

When I put the dropdown in the cellTemplate, it works, but it should also work in the **editable**CellTemplate.

Some code to see what I mean can be found here.

http://plnkr.co/edit/taPmlwLxZrF10jwwb1FX?p=preview

Does anyone know why that happens, and what could be done to work around it?

Comment: One question that might be related (currently unanswered) is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093892/angularjs-nggrid-issue-when-cell-editing-using-jquery-datepicker

Comment: and the versions you are using?

Comment: As can be seen in the plunker:
jquery-1.10.2
angularjs.org/1.2.3
ng-grid/2.0.7
ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.7.0.js

ivaynberg.github.com/select2/select2-master/select2.css
ivaynberg.github.com/select2/select2-master/select2.js
raw.github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2/master/src/select2.js

Comment: not sure if `ng-grid 2.0.7` works with `angularjs 1.2.3` they completely changed `angularjs` at 1.20 in terms of modules.

Comment: Grid works fine, exact same problem if I use Angular 1.1.1 instead of 1.2.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated the plunker with the solution (last grid shown).

http://plnkr.co/edit/taPmlwLxZrF10jwwb1FX?p=preview

The idea is that you should 'talk to ng-grid' exactly like the other editablCellTemplates do. These 'rules' aren't well defined in the documentation, but they could be deduced by looking at ng-grid's source code for the ng-input directive.

Basically, your own component should respond to the **ngGridEventStartCellEdit** event by focusing your editor element, and the most important thing is: *your component MUST emit the **ngGridEventEndCellEdit** event only when the cell loses focus* (or when you want the editor to disappear, like maybe when pressing enter or something).

So for this specific case I created my own directive that adds the necessary behaviour to a ui-select2 element, but I imagine you could understand what you'd have to do for your own specific case.

So, as an example, here is my ui-select2 specific directive:

```
app.directive(
            'uiSelect2EditableCellTemplate', 
            [ 
                function() {
                    return {
                        restrict: "A",
                        link: function ( scope, elm, attrs ) {
                            //make sure the id is set, so we can focus the ui-select2 by ID later on (because its ID will be generated from our id if we have one)
                            elm.attr( "id", "input-" + scope.col.index +  "-" + scope.row.rowIndex );

                            elm.on( 'click', function( evt ) {
                                evt.stopPropagation();
                            } ); 

                            elm.on( 'mousedown', function( evt ) {
                                evt.stopPropagation();
                            } ); 

                            //select2 has its own blur event !
                            elm.on( 'select2-blur', 
                                        function ( event ) { 
                                            scope.$emit( 'ngGridEventEndCellEdit' );                                                
                                        } 
                            );

                            scope.$on( 'ngGridEventStartCellEdit', function () {
                                //Event is fired BEFORE the new elements are part of the DOM, so try to set the focus after a timeout
                                setTimeout( function () {
                                                $( "#s2id_" + elm[0].id ).select2( 'open' );
                                            }, 10 );
                            } );


                        }
                    };
                }
            ] 
);
```

and my own editableCellTemplate would have to look something like this:

```
$scope.cellTemplateDropdownUiSelect3 =
'<select ui-select2-editable-cell-template ui-select2 ng-model="COL_FIELD" style="width: 90%" >' +
            '<option ng-repeat="(fkid, fkrow) in fkvalues_country" value="{{fkid}}" ng-selected="COL_FIELD == fkid" >{{fkrow}} ({{fkid}})</option>' +
'</select>' ;
```

A little bit of 'official' information can be found here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#editing-cells

Answer (score 2):

the template for datepicker

`<input  type="text" datepicker ng-model="COL_FIELD"/>`

and the angular directive would look like this.

```
 app.directive('datepicker',

      function () {
          return {

              restrict: 'A',
              require: '?ngModel',
              scope: {},
              link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

                  if (!ngModel) return;
                  var optionsObj = {};
                  optionsObj.dateFormat = 'dd/mm/yy';
                  optionsObj.onClose = function(){
                    scope.$emit( 'ngGridEventEndCellEdit' ); 
                  }


                  var updateModel = function (date) {
                                            scope.$apply(function () {
                                            ngModel.$setViewValue(date);
                                        });
                                };

                  optionsObj.onSelect = function (date, picker) {
                      updateModel(date);
                  };

                  ngModel.$render = function () {
                      element.datepicker('setDate', ngModel.$viewValue || '');
                  };

                scope.$on('ngGridEventStartCellEdit', function (obj) {
                    element.datepicker( "show" );  
                });

                scope.$on('ngGridEventStartCellEdit', function (obj) {
                    element.datepicker( "show" );  
                });
                element.datepicker(optionsObj);

              } 
          };
      });
```

Comment: Your answer really helped to setup datepicker. But I still dont get how I can save the row after setting the date. I thought the ngGridEventEndCellEdit will trigger the save. Can you help?